# Number formatting in R

Tags: r, formatting

I have an R vector `a = c(.45652356112, .0000063983562)`. And I want to format the numbers in this vector such that the resulting vector is `c(.46, 6.4e-06)`. When I do

```
format(a, digits=2, nsmall=2)
```

then the result is `c(4.6e-01, 6.4e-06)` rather than what I want. Apparently, each of the elements should be passed to the `format()` function separately to get the desired result. However, since the length of my original `a` is 50000, a for loop that calls `format()` for each element is way too slow. How can I get the desired formatting without a loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the format inside an `ifelse` condition

```
ifelse(a < 0.001, format(a, digits = 2, nsmall = 2), round(a, 2))
# [1] "0.46"    "6.4e-06"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was not aware of the `ifelse` function.

Comment: @user5054 You're welcome. It's a handy vectorised implementation of `if(...){ ... }else{ ... }`